# Marklogic Order By using Java API

Tags: marklogic

We have a requirement wherein we have to apply sorting to the query using Java API. I have a date field the query results needs to be ordered by that field. How can I achieve this using Java API?

Comment: You want to sort by date, but what are you querying for? Documents or just the date values? Can you post a bit of your code (that isn't sorting) or are you trying to figure out how to even get started doing that?

Comment: I am trying to get the documents in sorted order.. I just getting started, went through the Java API documentation. But could not find anything which I can use.

Answer (score 0):

When executing a search you can either reference a persisted query option, or apply it dynamically at query time.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_61605

> All search methods can also use persistent query options. *Persistent query options* are stored on the REST Server and referenced by name in future queries. Once created and persisted, you can apply query options to multiple searches, or even set to be the default options for all searches. Note that in XQuery, query option configurations are called options nodes.

> Some search methods support dynamic query options that you specify at search time. A combined query allows you to bundle a string and/or structured query with dynamic query options to further customize a search on a per search basis. You can also specify persistent query options with a combined query search. The search automatically merges the persistent (or default) query options and the dynamic query options together. For details, see [Apply Dynamic Query Options to Document Searches](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_76144).

An example of how to reference a persistent option:

```
// Use the persistent options previously saved as "myoptions"
RawQueryByExampleDefinition querydef =
  queryMgr.newRawQueryByExampleDefinition(rawHandle, "myoptions");
```

[Searching Using Combined Query](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_43047)

> Combined queries are useful for rapid prototyping during development and for applications that need to modify query options on a per query basis. The **RawCombinedQueryDefinition** class represents a combined query in the Java API.
>
> You can only create a combined query from raw XML or JSON; there is no builder class. A combined query can contain the following components, all optional:
>
> - A string query
> - A serialized structured query or cts query
> - **Query options**

A complete example demonstrating how to apply options sorting by `prop:last-modified` to a RawCombinedQueryDefinition:

```
DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient("localhost", 8000, "Documents",
            new DatabaseClientFactory.DigestAuthContext("admin", "admin"));
// create a manager for searching
QueryManager queryManager = client.newQueryManager();
StructuredQueryBuilder qb = queryManager.newStructuredQueryBuilder();
StructuredQueryDefinition structuredQuery = qb.collection("foo");

/* Combine the query definition and the search options into a combination query*/
String comboQuery = "<search xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search\">" +
        structuredQuery.serialize()
        + "<options>"
        + "  <sort-order type=\"xs:dateTime\" direction=\"descending\">"
        + "    <element ns='http://marklogic.com/xdmp/property' name='last-modified'/>"
        + "  </sort-order>"
        + "</options>"
        + "</search>";
RawCombinedQueryDefinition query = 
    queryManager.newRawCombinedQueryDefinition(new StringHandle(comboQuery).withFormat(Format.XML));

// create a handle for the search results
StringHandle resultsHandle = new StringHandle().withFormat(Format.XML);
// run the search
queryManager.search(query, resultsHandle);
// Retrieve and display the documents in this result set
System.out.println(resultsHandle);
// release the client
client.release();
```